# How can i login to Host Machine using ssh

Tags: ssh

The contents of `/etc/hosts` is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   dell
127.0.1.1   Hnname

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and i want to login on the dell@127.0.1.1. I know you have to do an `ssh dell@127.0.1.1`
the problem is it asks me for a password which i don't know.

Comment: All 127.x.y.z IP address are just yourself; you may as well use `ssh 0`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "The user must prove his/her identity to the remote machine using
     one of several methods depending on the protocol version used" Source: `man sh`

Answer (score 0):

To login to a machine using `ssh` you need:

```
ssh username@hostname
```

or

```
ssh username@host_ip
```

To `ssh` to the localhost i.e. the computer you are currently logged in, you can run any one of the following:

```
ssh username@127.0.0.1
ssh username@127.0.1.1
ssh username@localhost
ssh username@hostname
```

In your case you `dell` is the hostname, not a username. So, you need to use the correct username to log in.

In your case if you want to log in as user "foobar", you can run any one the following commands:

```
ssh foobar@127.0.0.1
ssh foobar@127.0.1.1
ssh foobar@localhost
ssh foobar@dell
ssh foobar@Hnname
```

Answer (score -3):

type

1. `ifconfig` , you will see ip address,suppose it is 10.42.0.1 and netmask is 255.255.255.0
   obviously 24 bits are for network address
2. type `nmap -n <ip address>/24`
   it will show no of host up with its ip address. suppose it is 10.42.0.23
3. type `ssh  hostname@<ip address of host>`,for remote login, password for host machine will be asked for remote login.